# storing date in coredata swift

Tags: swift, date, core-data

I have a textfield connected to a date picker

I am then trying to store the selected date into core data,

My log off the date picked by the user seems ok:

2016-01-29 00:00:00 +0000 [I strip the time component with some code]

This is converted into a String and displayed in the textfield called startDate.

```
func handleDatePicker(sender: UIDatePicker) {
        let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEE, dd MMM YYYY"
        startDate.text = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(sender.date)
    }
```

Now the strange thing is that when I try and store this into CoreData and convert the string back into a date (the attribute I am saving it into is configured as a Date)

```
let cont = self.context
        let newCustomer = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Customer", inManagedObjectContext: cont)
        let aCust = Customer(entity: newCustomer!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: cont)

let DF = NSDateFormatter()
        DF.dateFormat = "EEE, dd MMM YYYY"
        aCust.c15das = DF.dateFromString(startDate.text!)
        print("Saved Date: \(DF.dateFromString(startDate.text!))")
```

Now the log prints out:

2015-12-25 00:00:00 +0000

Why the difference? How can I stop this happening?

Sorry if its something obvious that I am not spotting.

Comment: This seems to bee a wrong database entry you pick. Did you store already some dates into your database?

Comment: @Anokrize No this is among the first dates I am trying to save into the database. Even when I changed the date to the 25 or 26 Jan, the date stored ended up being the 23 December 2015

Comment: So if you type something in, it is always the same wrong date or always a wrong different date?

Comment: @Anokrize                let DF = NSDateFormatter()
        DF.dateFormat = "EEE, dd MMM YYYY"
        aCust!.c15das = DF.dateFromString("Fri, 29 Jan 2016")
        let str = "Fri, 29 Jan 2016"
        print("Edited Date: \(removeReferenceToTime(DF.dateFromString(str)!))")

Comment: As you can see I literally typed the string in as it appears in my textfield and the result printed out is: Edited Date: Fri, 25 Dec 2015

Comment: So I guess always the same wrong different dates

Comment: So you always get the date of 29 Jan 2016, no matter which date you insert?

Comment: No, for the 28 Jan 2016, I get 24 Dec 2015 and so on @Anokrize

Comment: Ok so one thing I can see is that you always get the same date minus 1 month and minus 4 days. Try it with a different date if this assumption is right.

Comment: @Anokrize Yes that's right, tried with several dates - seeing the pattern, but why

Comment: where is this happening? if you try to cast the string back to the date or if you save it to the db?

Comment: When I try and save it to the db, and when I try and cast the string back to a date as in the print example above @Anokrize

Comment: I will test it on mine

Comment: Thanks, I will check back in morning - need to get some sleep ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"EEE, dd MMM YYYY"` -> `YYYY`: ["Week of Year Calendar", aka "ISO  Week Date System"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date). The first week does not start on the first January. If the January 1st is either Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday or Thursday, the whole week is the first week of the new year. if it is Friday, Saturday or Sunday the week is the 53rd week of the last year. So this is a calendar with year that only have integral weeks. Either 52 or 53, rather than 365 or 366 days.
In this calendar January 29th would be the 5th day of the 4th week of the year 2016 — 2016-W4-5. This system does not know months and therefor your date is nonsense.

You want `"EEE, dd MMM yyyy"`, as `yyyy` indicates a year that starts on 1st of January and ends after 31st of December — The Gregorian Year.

---

> [I strip the time component with some code]

You shouldn't do that. Rather NSCalendar's method to get a date at the beginning of the day.

```
var today: NSDate?
cal.rangeOfUnit(.Day, startDate: &today, interval: nil, forDate: date)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but cal.startOfDayForDate does not account for daylight savings so if I select 25 March 2016 from picker, my log prints, "24 Mar 2016, 23:00"

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, that worked for me:

```
let dateString = "Fri, 29 Jan 2016" // change to your date format

let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEE, dd MMM yyyy"
dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "UTC")

let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateString)
print(date!)
```